# How to go on last page from number of pages using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

[image]

This is the Screenshot of my UI and HTML DOM.

I want to go to the last page one this I can do is pressing next button many times, but I don't know how many time it should be pressed, so i don't think so its a better way.
Can you suggest me better way using selenium commands.

I used this command (pressing next continuously):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('html/body/div[2]/div/section[8]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/table/tfoot/tr/td/div/ul/li[5]/a').click()
```

Comment: Do you have a URL as an example? Also, it's better to put the relevant DOM as code instead of in an image.

Comment: you can take the example as gmail.com...in which we have to scroll down pages to see the first mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `try/except` like:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

while True:
    try:
         WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//li[not(@class="disabled")]/a[contains(text(), "Next")]'))).click()
    except TimeoutException:
        break
```

This should allow you to click `Next` button until last page (until button become disabled)

P.S. You should not use absolute `XPath`, e.g. `html/body/div[2] ... /div/ul/li[5]/a` as it's sensitive to changes in `DOM`. Use target element's attributes or its parent/child nodes to create relative `XPath`

Comment: when I use this just to click the next button: **driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//a[text()="Next"]').click()**    it gives me error **NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[text()=\"Next\"]"}**......when I use the code suggested by you it gives me an error  **invalid syntax near except**

Comment: When I use the code given by you, it gives me an error **except TimeoutException: SyntaxError: invalid syntax**   Then I have updated the code by :  `While True: try:WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(text(), "Next")]'))).click()     except:TimeoutException:   break` .Then the code is continuously pressing next button because its not getting any exception. One more thing What is this TimeoutException in your code?

Comment: Oh, yes, I forgot to add `try` :) `WebDriverWait(driver, 10)` returns element if condition (element is clickable) is `True`, but if it still not clickable after 10 seconds pass `TimeoutException` should be raised

Comment: Does your script execution ends after last page reached? Or it hangs?

Comment: When I am using this command continuously `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(text(), "Next")]'))).click()` , it is not giving me any exception. After last page also I am able to click the next button.

Comment: Yes, my script is hanging as it is continuously pressing next button. I cannot do any other thing in the UI also. I have to do cntrl+C to stop.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Check it and let me know the result